# for loop inside the if and else if

Tags: java

```
if(code==1)
                {
                System.out.print("Enter product number: ");
                int productnumber=Integer.parseInt(a.readLine());
                System.out.print("Enter product name: ");
                String productname=a.readLine();
                System.out.print("Enter price: ");
                int price1=Integer.parseInt(a.readLine());
                System.out.println("");
                {
                        int p=0;
                            for(int q=1;q<=1;q++)
                            {   
                                System.out.println("1. Maintenance");
                                System.out.println("2. Transaction");
                                System.out.println("");

                                System.out.print("Enter Code: ");
                                int code1=Integer.parseInt(a.readLine());
                                System.out.println("");
                            }
                }
                {
                int w;
                for(productnumber=2; productnumber<=2; productnumber++)
                {   
                System.out.println("Product number: "+productnumber);
                System.out.print("Product name: ");
                String prodname=a.readLine();
                System.out.print("Price: ");
                int price2=Integer.parseInt(a.readLine());
                System.out.println("");
                }
                }
                }
                     else if(code==2)
                         {
                            System.out.println("Display List of Product-Prices");
                            System.out.print("Display product number: ");
                            int productnumber2=Integer.parseInt(a.readLine());
                            System.out.println("Total: ");
                            System.out.print("Payment: ");
                            int payment=Integer.parseInt(a.readLine());
                            }
                        }
```

//What's the problem in this code guys? There's an option which is the **1. Maintenance** and **2. Transaction**. If i press the number 1, it will read this following codes:

```
int w;
                for(productnumber=2; productnumber<=2; productnumber++)
                {   
                System.out.println("Product number: "+productnumber);
                System.out.print("Product name: ");
                String prodname=a.readLine();
                System.out.print("Price: ");
                int price2=Integer.parseInt(a.readLine());
                System.out.println("");
```

//But if i press the number 2, it will read the same code with the number 1.. What will I do to read the statements inside the "else if(code==2)" when i press the number 2? Thankyou for those who will help me. :)

Comment: The logical error is going to be somewhere in setting the value of `code` so showing us what is within that if statement isn't going to help much.

Comment: How you are getting value `1` or `2` in variable `code` ?

Comment: What's the point of `for(int q=1;q<=1;q++)`?

Comment: Maybe i will remove that code. Sorry..

Comment: Sir/ Ma'am Leigero, what do you mean by setting the value of **code**?

Comment: in case you don't know, ctrl+shift+F in eclipse will fix the indentation quickly.

Comment: @msknapp I think you mean CTRL+I (like indent). CTRL+SHIFT+F is Find/Replace.

Comment: @Alexander_Winter: no, I use ctrl+shift+F every day, it's format, ctrl+f without the shift is find.  maybe your IDE is configured differently.

Comment: @msknapp No I just checked and we are both right. CTRL + SHIFT + F is format and CTRL + I is indent. You can indent selected code with CTRL + I, but CTRL + SHIFT + F format your whole code.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to show us complete code. Only then can we understand where are you going wrong. Based on above whatever snippet you've provided i've build a wrapper around it and ran the code it seems to be fine. Look below:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class test123 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
        BufferedReader a = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("Enter your code : ");
        int code = Integer.parseInt(a.readLine());
        System.out.println();
        if (code == 1) {
            System.out.print("Enter product number: ");
            int productnumber = Integer.parseInt(a.readLine());
            System.out.print("Enter product name: ");
            String productname = a.readLine();
            System.out.print("Enter price: ");
            int price1 = Integer.parseInt(a.readLine());
            System.out.println("");
            {
                int p = 0;
                for (int q = 1; q <= 1; q++) {
                    System.out.println("1. Maintenance");
                    System.out.println("2. Transaction");
                    System.out.println("");

                    System.out.print("Enter Code: ");
                    int code1 = Integer.parseInt(a.readLine());
                    System.out.println("");
                }
            }
            {
                int w;
                for (productnumber = 2; productnumber <= 2; productnumber++) {
                    System.out.println("Product number: " + productnumber);
                    System.out.print("Product name: ");
                    String prodname = a.readLine();
                    System.out.print("Price: ");
                    int price2 = Integer.parseInt(a.readLine());
                    System.out.println("");
                }
            }
        } else if (code == 2) {
            System.out.println("Display List of Product-Prices");
            System.out.print("Display product number: ");
            int productnumber2 = Integer.parseInt(a.readLine());
            System.out.println("Total: ");
            System.out.print("Payment: ");
            int payment = Integer.parseInt(a.readLine());
        }
        a.close();
    }
}
```

This looks fine. Show us your complete code. for further investigation.